# Python selenium and chrome in server linux without root

Tags: python, linux, selenium, google-chrome

I need to use the selenium python library in a hosting, the server is shared, where I don't have root permissions.
The library is installed, it does not give error when importing.
Download the ChromeDriver for Linux and save it in a folder of my user.
Running the python file gives:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ../chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

If I look for what version the server has with: `google-chrome --version`, I get `google-chrome: command not found`

I understand that need to install chrome to run the script. Is there any way to install it locally (ie for my user)? I can not use `sudo`.

Anyone who will use it in this way that can recommend me the steps to follow? Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to use `google-chrome-stable` to launch the chrome. But you need to launch it in headless mode.

Comment: @sraw but Google-chrome --version give command not found, any way to install local with my user?